# harmonic function. How to prove?

Tags: derivatives, harmonic-functions

I've with prove if $1 \over |x|$ is a harmonic function.
I know with for a harmonic function, $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$, but I don't know how to derivate ${1 \over |x|} dx$. And I don't know how to derivate $f_{yy}$ for this function because it haven't $y$ terms. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are 1-dimensional harmonic functions.

Comment: @gary Affine functions?

Comment: @scineram: For some reason I thought we only considered 2D, apparently not. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

This $|x|$ should mean $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. This would be harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: In 2D $(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$ is not harmonic, even away from zero.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic function $\phi$ satisfies Laplace equation: $\Delta \phi = 0$
Switching to spherical coordinates give: $$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\delta}{\delta r}r^2\frac{\delta}{\delta r} * \frac{1}{r} = 0$$
It is not harmonic in any other dimension except $n = 3$